# How to Fix scrollarea to the screen in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am having a webpage as show in img. the left side is a scroll area and right side is normal div[image]

Now what i dont want the gap between two horizontal scroll bars.I want to fix left side for screen and only right side should be scrollable.

Comment: Post your code as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give div height in px and make two separate `div` for right and left sides and apply `position:fixed` css